# How can I make a slide rule in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have recently found out about slide rules from a [Scientific American article](http://www.uvm.edu/~pdodds/teaching/courses/2009-08UVM-300/docs/others/2006/stoll2006a.pdf) and I like them very much. However, I have never got access to a *real* slide rule. So I made my own slide rule using my printer with the help of [this pdf](http://www.scientificamerican.com/media/pdf/Slide_rule.pdf). However, the slide rule that I have made does not have many scales whereas real slide rules [like this one](http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/sliderules/side1.jpg), have a lot of scales.

So I thought that maybe I will be able to make a better one using TikZ. I started making it and got stuck here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=0pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
~\vfill
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (14,20);
\draw (8.75,0) -- (8.75,20);
\draw [dashed] (1.75,0) -- (1.75,20);
\draw [dashed] (7,0) -- (7,20);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \x in {2,...,18}{\draw (0,\x) -- ++(0.15,0);}
\node [rotate=90] at (0.5,1.5) {C};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}\\

\vfill
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make a logarithmic scale in TikZ.
So please tell me just the basic syntax to create the logarithmic scale.
I will do the rest.

Comment: They are a thing of beauty (and I can still use one).  I inherited my Dad's slide rule, which he used to help design the original heat shield bringing the first object ever back from orbit: http://drexel.edu/mem/news/archive/2012-07-19%20It%20was%20a%20Great%20Time%20to%20be%20an%20Engineer/ .  Funny thing is, when I tutor kids in math, and sometimes bring one along to demonstrate, they look at it like a thing of magic, the way we did when calculators were first introduced.  Perspective is an interesting thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logarithmic ticks can be easily plotted by iterating the function `f[n,x]=n+log(x)` for `n>=0` and `1<=x<=9` where both `n` and `x` are integers.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\psset{xunit=3cm}

\def\f(#1,#2){(#1+log(#2))}

\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(4,1)
    \psline[linecolor=blue](4,0)
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    \foreach \n in {0,...,3}{%
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{% 10 (instead of 9) is used here to make sure the last line is drawn.
            \pstVerb{/xxx {{\f(\n,\i)} exec I2P} def}%
            \psline(!xxx -1)(!xxx 1)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Translation to TikZ

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\def\f(#1,#2){#1+log10(#2)}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \foreach \n in {0,...,3}{%
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{% 10 (instead of 9) is used here to make sure the last line is drawn.
            \draw[red] ({\f(\n,\i)},-1) -- ({\f(\n,\i)},1);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can i do this in Tikz?

Comment: I wasted much time to locate the `log` function in TikZ. It is actually named as `log10`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made most of it, but can you tell me what formula is used for the sin and cos scale?

Comment: @Kartik: What does it mean? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I was asking that how can I make the "sin" scale on the slide rule.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the sine and other scales, the International Slide Rule Museum has a page that shows the formulas to compute common slide rule scales.

http://sliderulemuseum.com/SR_Scales.htm

Be careful with the Trig scales (S, T, ST) as they are for restricted domains.  (For example, the S scale is between 5.7 and 90 degrees.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this would be better as a comment than as an answer.